# Is there any way apart from using key vault, agentless pipeline and parameters to provide user input during pipeline runtime in azure?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-build-task, azure-pipelines-tasks

I'm trying to provide user input during pipeline runtime but not able to give it. is there any way I can achieve this in azure pipeline apart from using parameters or using key vault to provide the input during manual validation.

Tried creating an ansible task to prompt the user to enter the input but not able to achieve it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is Azure Pipeline Interactive? Can User Input be Used during runtime of Pipeline Stages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77859065/is-azure-pipeline-interactive-can-user-input-be-used-during-runtime-of-pipeline)

Comment: Hi @SejaNaik, Have you got a chance to check the answers below? If either of the workarounds to use KV or Library works for you, you may consider this which can help others with similar concerns. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Azure DevOps build pipelines are non-interactive, and there is no way to ask for user input during a pipeline run, unless you are using manual intervention and changing data in third party storage areas/vault like you suggest.

You can [suggest the feature here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/home), and it may get developed.

Comment: Thank you for the response. can you please provide some more information about using manual intervention?

Comment: @SejalNaik I have answered this stack overflow thread question here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77862243/23215931

Answer (score 0):

Since Azure Pipelines are non-interactive, there is no way out-of-the-box to input variable values **during** a pipeline run.

While inspired by @ScottRichards insightful [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77859065/is-azure-pipeline-interactive-can-user-input-be-used-during-runtime-of-pipeline/77862243#77862243), you may consider using the workaround below to update the values of the variables from pipelines library (variable group) during the process of a running pipeline.

Here is a simple YAML pipeline to use a variable group (in the `job` scope).

```
stages:
- stage: StageA
  jobs:
  - job: Job1
    variables:
    - group: VG-Job
    steps:
    - script: echo $(Var1)

  - job: Job2
    dependsOn: Job1
    variables:
    - group: VG-Job
    steps:
    - script: echo $(Var1)
```

1. Setup the variable group with the name `VG-Job`; in the variable group, add a variable `$(Var1)` with the original value `ValueXXXXX`;
   [image]
2. Enable `Approvals` check for this variable group;
   [image]
   [image]
3. When running the pipeline, it will suspend the execution of `StageA` to wait for the approval by the approver to use the variable group resource `VG-Job`;
   [image]
4. Before approval, the approver may update the value of the variable `$(Var1)` in this variable group and proceed to approve and resume the pipeline stage;
   [image]
5. The output value of the variable `$(Var1)` during the pipeline run will be the updated value `ValueYYYYY` rather than its original value `ValueXXXXX`, since the value of a variable in a variable group is processed at [runtime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch);
   [image]

Kindly be also advised that,

> Checks are a mechanism available to the resource owner to control if and when a **stage** in a pipeline can consume a resource (like variable group in our case). As an owner of a resource, such as an environment (variable group), you can define checks that must be satisfied before a **stage** consuming that resource can start.

This is to say for `Job2` in the **same** stage as that of `Job1`, it will **not** suspend the pipeline again to ask for approval.

Hope the workaround may help resolve your queries.